# Delete rows without values

Tags: sas, rows

I have a table with loads of missing values and I will like to delete the rows if all three column values are missing.

I tired cmiss (of *all*) but that is deleting all values not just second obs.

In the example below, I need only 2nd row deleted, not the 4th..

codes I have used:

```
if click =. then delete;
else if activity=. then delete;
else if impression=. then delete;
run;
```

this did not help :/

The table is in this form

```
obs     Clicks     Activity     Impression
1          2           7            100
2          -           -            -
3          3           9            170
4          6           2            -
```

I will like to delete row 2 and 4, because they have a missing number.
Anyone?

Comment: Your language is unclear.  You want to delete if _any_ are missing, or if _all_ are missing?  Row 2 is _all_, Row 4 is _any_.

Comment: Sorry. I want to delete if all are missing.

Comment: If you want to delete row 4, or if (also possible) `activity=.` (by itself), then the word you're looking for is *any* are missing not *all*.  If *all* are missing, you would *only delete row 4*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this example :

```
data set4;
    infile datalines missover;
    input VAR1 VAR2;
datalines;
1 2

6 9
4  
run;

data set5;
set set4;
if missing(VAR1)  and missing(VAR2) then delete;
run;

data set6;
set set4;
if missing(VAR1)  or missing(VAR2) then delete;
run;
```

if you want to delete the row because all the variables are missing then use AND.
if you want to delete the row because any variable is missing then use OR.

Comment: Damn! if and then does it. This was easy. Simply embarrassing on my part. Thanks for the response!